# Entity Framework - Code First - Update won't change Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I just can't find any code that changes the foreign key. How do I tell the context that the foreign key has changed so that it updates the database? I have been attempting to get this to work for 2 months now:

**These are the models:**

```
namespace MyApp.WebApi.Models
{

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key - Project Status

    public virtual ProjectStatus ProjectStatus { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectStatus
{
    public int ProjectStatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HerculesWebApiContext : DbContext
{
    public HerculesWebApiContext() : base("name=HerculesWebApiContext") { }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectStatus> ProjectStatuses { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) { }
}
}
```

This is the controller for the Web API:

```
namespace MyApp.WebApi.Controllers
{
public class ProjectController : ApiController
{
    private HerculesWebApiContext db = new HerculesWebApiContext();

    public void PutProject(int id, [FromBody]Project project)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); 
        if (id != project.ProjectId) throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); 


        // I need some code here to tell EF that the FK has changed

        db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;


        // Try catch around this

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The above code will not update the Project Status Foreign Key even if it has changed in the JSON object that is passed to the function. The object is returned in the same format that the Web API provided it but with the Project Status object updated:

```
[{"ProjectStatus":{"ProjectStatusId":2,"Name":"Started"},"ProjectId":3,"Description":"test description","Name":"test project"}]
```

I have tried:

```
db.Projects.Attach(db.Projects.Single(c => c.ProjectId == project.ProjectId));

        ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext
            .ApplyCurrentValues("Projects", project);
```

I have also tried:

```
db.Entry(project.ProjectStatus).CurrentValues.SetValues(new ProjectStatus { ProjectStatusId = project.ProjectStatus.ProjectStatusId });
```

I have also tried this:

```
var per = new ProjectStatus { ProjectStatusId = project.ProjectStatus.ProjectStatusId }; // create the stub
db.ProjectStatuses.Attach(per);
db.Entry(project.ProjectStatus).CurrentValues.SetValues(per);
```

These are the table T-SQL files that are automatically created from my models:

**Projects Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Projects] (
[ProjectId]                     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Description]                   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Name]                          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[ProjectStatus_ProjectStatusId] INT            NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Projects] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProjectId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Projects_dbo.ProjectStatus_ProjectStatusId] FOREIGN KEY ([ProjectStatus_ProjectStatusId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ProjectStatus] ([ProjectStatusId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**Project Statuses Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProjectStatus] (
[ProjectStatusId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ProjectStatus] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProjectStatusId] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Aren't you missing `public int ProjectStatusId { get; set; }` in the `Project` model?

Comment: I did have that before but it was creating 2 fields for the Project Status in the Project DB table. This seems to create the DB correctly with 1 field in the project table with FK relationship  `ProjectStatus_ProjectStatusId`

Comment: Perhaps because none of the primary keys are explicitly specified? Add the attribute `[Key]` to `ProjectId` in `Project` and 'ProjectStatusId` in `ProjectStatus`

Comment: @DavidG - I have added the T-SQL scripts that are generated to the question above. It appears that the primary keys and foreign keys are being generated correctly?

Comment: I guessed that, but was curious as to what would happen if you put back in the `ProjectStatusId` along with the explicitly specified `Key` attributes, would that solve your issue?

Comment: @DavidG - Wow that worked!! The reason that I removed it beforehand was that I was getting "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred" error. But I have realised that in my JSON object passed to the Put method I needed to update the foreign key in 2 places as follows: `"ProjectStatus":{"ProjectStatusId":2,"Name":"Started"},"ProjectStatusId":2,"ProjectId":8,"Description":"lorem ipsum","Name":"Lorem ipsum"}` - I was expecting EF to automatically link the 2 properties, but I guess I just have to update it in both places if I want to use the virtual reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things. First explicitly state your primary keys for each class.

Add the `[Key]` attribute to

`Project` class,  above the line `public int ProjectId { get; set; }`

`ProjectStatus` class, above the line `public int ProjectStatusId { get; set; }`

Secondly add the property for your foreign key to your `Project` class. Add this line:

```
public int ProjectStatusId { get; set; }
```